# How to display encoded HTML in browser

Tags: c#, html, html-encode, quill

I am using [Quill](https://quilljs.com/) Rich Text Editor.

[image]

This is what I get from the rich text box:

```
<p>This is my rich HTML Text</p>
```

I understand, it is not safe to display user input directly in the browser, so I HTML encode this string and get this:

```
&lt;p&gt;This is my rich HTML Text&lt;&#x2F;p&gt;
```

Now I copy this encoded string inside an HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
    <h4>This is my Template</h4>
    <div class='message'> &lt;p&gt;This is my rich HTML Text&lt;&#x2F;p&gt; </div>
</body>
```

But now, when I open the template in the browser, I see the encoded HTML as string:

This is my Template
     <p>This is my rich HTML Text</p>

How can I both ensure user input is encoded and display the output HTML correctly?

---

### Update

Looks like Quill is already encoding the HTML, if I type the following:
[image]

In my JavaScript function, I noticed that HTML is already encoded:
[image]

Am I safe to use this user input?

Comment: You can't really have your cake and eat it too. You want the user to supply markup/HTML, but you don't want to treat it as such. The only solution is to sanitise the HTML server side with a comprehensive, deep reaching, DOM-aware, whitelist based sanitiser which removes all tags and attributes except for specific safe ones. For that it greatly depends on what server-side language you're using.

Comment: With a correctly set [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and a halfway-decent markdown editor [such as Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) there is minimal risk to having the HTML code set as-is *within* the `<textarea>` input element.

Comment: @deceze: thanks a lot... so if I want to use the rich text from user, I have to directly show it in the browser? Is there anyway to mitigate for XSS?

Comment: Yyyeeessss… *server side comprehensive deep reaching DOM-aware whitelist based sanitiser*…

Comment: @Martin: thanks a lot... I think you have answered my question... I am using Quill Rich Text Editor, and looks like it already encode HTML... Looks like I don't need to double encode the HTML... Do you know about Quill and if it is safe?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini  — Since an attacker can bypass Quill and submit HTML directly, it doesn't matter if it is safe or not. The code which puts the user input into the document is what needs to be safe.

Comment: @Quentin: thanks a lot, I have updated my answer... to show how I get the input from Quill. Are you able to elaborate a bit on your comment? I am not sure if I can trust the Quill encoding and also not sure how can an attacker by pass quill as you pointed out?

Comment: An attacker can make an HTTP request directly (from the browser console, from the cURL command line program, from Postman, etc, etc) to `/Communication/ContactAdvertiser` containing whatever data they want.

Comment: @Quentin: thanks a lot... So I really have to encode the input in my JS function... and if I do that, I cannot display it correctly! I am stcuk? What should I do then?

Comment: "So I really have to encode the input in my JS function" — No. See the very first comment on your question (by deceze). Don't encode it. Don't do it client-side.

Comment: I don't know what server-side language you're using, and it doesn't look like you're going to tell us, but I've closed this as dupe of a PHP-specific question for now, since this doesn't seem to be going anywhere otherwise.

Comment: I ended up using [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) to Sanitize user input on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for a Markdown convertor like https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown

Comment: Thanks @freek. I wish people who down vote would leave a comment too, so we know why...

Comment: The input is *HTML*, not Markdown.

Comment: Also, since Markdown allows raw HTML to be included in it, it is **as vulnerable to XSS** as just allowing raw HTML directly. https://jsbin.com/bodekewaja/1/edit?html,js,console !!